# After deiniting webView, video embedded in the webView is still playing - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, webview, wkwebview

My `ViewController` has a `WKWebView` that embeds JavaScript with a video. 
When I pop the view controller, `deinit` is called. In `deinit`, I nullify everything that related to `webView`.

However, after popping the view controller, the audio from the video is still playing. What am I missing?

```
deinit
{
    webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
    webView.navigationDelegate = nil
    webView.scrollView.delegate = nil
    webView.removeFromSuperview()
    webView = nil
}
```

Comment: try with webView.delegate = nil

Comment: Also, make sure `deinit` is actually getting called. I know it may sound stupid but happened to me before:)

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder WKWebView doesn't have delegate

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier it is called

Comment: Can you stop the video from JS? If so, send a message to your script before removing the `WKWebView`, [using this library](https://github.com/coshx/caravel).

Comment: @AdrienCadet but why doesn't it stop by itself? Should the webview be deallocated?

Comment: @Luda It should be an expected behavior instead. But as `WKWebView` is still in beta, it might not work as expected. Just send a signal to your JS counterpart when exiting your controller or removing your web view, to stop the video.

Comment: @AdrienCadet, this is not an option for me. I just need to dealocate/deinit it natively.

Comment: Do you have a block with a reference to the webview ? I had this kind of issues. Video was still playing after deinit, because of a strong reference to the webview in a block.

Comment: @Beuj, I have a observer on the webView, but I remove it in the deinit: webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress"). But say you were right, how can this be fixed?

Comment: @Luda: Can you share your code with us? It would be better to help us figure out what's wrong

Comment: I suspect you may have retain cycled WKWebView somewhere. Subclass it and see if its deinit is getting called. If not you can use instruments to see what objects are pointing to it strongly.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure it is because of some cycled retains of the webView. Try by setting empty data to webview in 'deinit'. This may solve your problem, but you have to fix cycled retain of your webview.

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "about:blank")))
```

Comment: Something else fixed my problem, But I'll give you the 100 point cous I did found out that I have a retain cycle

Comment: I got the same issue no luck tried Arun's answer also

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed the issue:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    webView.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue due to a retain cycle (holding onto self in a UIBarButtonItem's handler block) - views don't retain their subviews automatically so I think the removeFromSuperview() call was a workaround that didn't fix the root cause here. Just posting this for future readers who may get this idea